# Filter in golang mongodb

Tags: mongodb, go

Currently I learn to create restful api with golang and mongodb. Actually I am beginner in both. I use [mongodb-go-driver](https://godoc.org/go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver) and I learn to use filter when we want to use `find()` function. But I have some that I don't understand. What is the different between `filter := bson.M{"_id": "abcd"}` and `filter := bson.M{{"_id": "abcd"}}`? Thank you

Comment: `filter := bson.M{{"_id": "abcd"}}` doesn't compile, so I don't know what you're asking. Maybe you mean `filter := []bson.M{{"_id": "abcd"}}`? That's a slice, a slice of "filters", most often used when specifying stages of a MongoDB aggregation.

Comment: @RiefSapthana. I think you meant `filter := bson.D{{"_id": "abcd"}}`.  Use `bson.D{{}}` when order matters, for example, multiple fields in the query filter.  Either one `bson.D` or `bson.M` as filters, mongo engine is intelligent enough to give you the same result.

Comment: Thank you @simagix @icza, what is the double braces `bson.D{{}}` mean? Does `bson.M` have `bson.M{{}}` form?

Comment: I got example like this `filter := bson.M{"_id": id}` and this `filter := bson.D{{"name", "Ash"}}` so why `bson.D` use double braces `{{}}`? What does it mean?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Refer to the source code, https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-go-driver/blob/master/bson/primitive/primitive.go

`bson.D`, internally is `primitive.D`, which is `[]primitive.E`, which is a `struct`.  `bson.M`, internally is `primitive.M`, which is `map[string]interface{}`.  You put in key/value in `bson.M` but use document (struct) in `bson.D`.

It is better to explain it using 2 parameters, e.g. search for `a = 1 and b = 2`.  You syntax will be: `bson.M{"a": 1, "b": 2}` or `bson.D{{"a": 1}, {"b": 2}}`

Answer (score 3):

```
//Filter Part
if filter != nil {
    if len(filter.Status) > 0 {
        query = append(query, bson.M{"status": bson.M{"$in": filter.Status}})

    }
}
d.Shared.BsonToJSONPrint(query)
//Getting Total count
totalCount, err := col.Find(func() bson.M {
    if query != nil {
        if len(query) > 0 {
            return bson.M{"$and": query}
        }
    }
    return bson.M{}
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
    var user []models.User

    var findQuery []bson.M

    coll := db.C(constants.USERTABLE)

    if name != nil {
        if len(name) > 0 {
            query = append(query, bson.M{"name": bson.M{"$in": name}})

        }
    }

    if status != nil {
        if len(status) > 0 {
            query = append(query, bson.M{"status": bson.M{"$in": status}})

        }
    }

    findQuery = append(findQuery, bson.M{"$match": func() bson.M {
        if query != nil {
            if len(query) > 0 {
                return bson.M{"$and": query}
            }
        }
        return bson.M{}
    }()})

    shared.BsonToJSONPrint(query)

    err = coll.Pipe(findQuery).All(&user)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    return user, nil
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The client decodes the result to a `bson.D` document by default, this is represented as an array, which is not the document shape we want.

To overwrite this behaviour you have to decode to a `bson.M`, which is a simple `map` and has the same shape of the document in database

```
res := collection.FindOne(ctx, p.Where)

if res.Err() == mongo.ErrNoDocuments {
    return nil, nil
}
if res.Err() != nil {
        return nil, res.Err()
}
var document bson.M = make(bson.M) // important
err = res.Decode(document)
```